# How can I edit a URL obtained from RSS

Tags: javascript, rss

I have edited this RSS feed CodePen http://codepen.io/RobKirby/pen/azwwvM?editors=001 to display Wordpress posts http://tomcandy.com/blogtest/ however my RSS feed on wordpress links to images only 150px wide. If I could delete the last 6 characters of the url it would link to the full size image, however I can't understand how to edit the url in js. Within html  gives the url for each entry, but I can't work out how to slice it before using it in the html.

```
$('#feed').feeds({
                    feeds: {
                        feed1: 'https://tomcandy.wordpress.com/feed/',

                    },
                    xml: true,
                    max: 6,                     
                        // Date sorting omitted to simplify code                 

                    // // Template used to render each entry 
                            entryTemplate: 
                                                                '<! if (source == "feed1") { !>' +
  //need url to be 6 characters shorter /  var newurl = mediaGroups[0].contents[3].url;
                                                                    '<a class="feeds-entry feeds-source-<!=source!>" target="_blank" href="<!=link!>" title="<!=title!>" style="background-image:url(<!=mediaGroups[0].contents[3].url!>);" data-date="<!=title!>">' +
                                            '<div class="label"><!=title!></div>' +
                                                    '<div class="blur" style="background-image:url(<!=mediaGroups[0].contents[3].url!>);"></div>' +
                                            '<div class="content">' +
                                                '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' +
                                                '<p>View on Wordpress</p>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</a>' +

                                    '<! } !>'

                });
```

Another option is to copy all the rss across to my website editing only the urls, but that would be a last resort.
Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using

```
 preprocess: function ( feed ) {
       this.newurl = this.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url.slice(0,-6);
}
```